# JQuery traversing up to add a class

Tags: jquery, html

Im having difficulties highlighting a tab from a sub category.
This first piece of code is a singular tab with **class='active_pat_tab'** as the identifier for highlighting the tab. The class is added dynamicaly through a variable that identifies the **id** of the containin **li** in this case **id='tabAssessDetails'**.

```
<li class='tabs_item' id='tabAssessDetails'>
    <a href='#page-1' class='active_pat_tab'>
        <span>Assess Details</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

but,
In the example below I have a tab with two sub categories. It is still identified by the incoming variable, but in this case the identified item is a sub catagory of the tab that needs to be highlighted. **id='tabPhysicalExamination'** is say the tab that was requested, but the dynamic class addition should go to the parent li's a... see the 3rd example code.

```
<li class='has-sub tabs_item'>
    <a href='#page-2'><span>Observation</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class='tabsub' id='tabCareLevel'>
            <a href='#page-17'><span>Care Level</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='tabsub' id='tabPhysicalExamination'>
            <a href='#page-3'><span>Physical examination</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

what it should look like:

```
<li class='has-sub tabs_item'>
    <a href='#page-2' class='active_pat_tab'><span>Observation</span></a>
</li>
```

I have tried a few things including

```
$( "li.tabsub" ).closest( "a" ).addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

and

```
$( "li.tabsub" ).parents( "li.tabs_item" ).addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

but I have failed to get the class to be added to the correct place.

PS: There is no click on the tab. This is coming from a different page to a specific tab. I dont think I can use click in this instance. or am i missing something?

Comment: your question a bit unclear, providing a jsfiddle would help.you have multiple list items with the class tabsub.. so you have to handle link click & then do the $(this) to get the parent li.tabsub

Comment: @Krishna - There is no click on the tab. This is coming from a different page to a specific tab. I dont think I can use click in this instance. or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your starting element, you want to get the containing `<ul>`, then the `<a>` element before it, so:

```
$('#' + id).closest('ul').prev('a').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

I've used `'#' + id` because you said you have a variable identifying the ID of the starting element, and from the question that seems like it's called `id`.

Comment: Im dont know if I should laugh or not. I know it is supposed to be simple to do this, but then its always that simple solution you dont think about. Thanks Anthony, works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$( "li.tabsub" ).closest("li.tabs_item").children("a").addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

References

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do:

```
$('#page2').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

Right now it doesn't do it because your #page2 anchor is siblings with the ul, so you can not select it with .closest().

Also your `$( "li.tabsub" ).parents( "li.tabs_item" ).addClass('active_pat_tab');` wouldn't work because, that class is not your anchor element.

other way you can do it without using the id is:

```
$( "li.tabsub" ).closest( "li.tabs_item" ).find('a:first').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```